# Why my localStorage is not saved on refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have the following code to insert data in my LocalStorage :

```
 var data_token = $('.temp_information').data('token');
 var token = JSON.stringify(data_token);
 localStorage.setItem('Access_token', token);
```

When I check my LocalStorage, I have my data :

```
Key : Access_token ; 
value: {"access_token":"XXXXXXX","token_type":"Bearer"}
```

but when I refresh my page, the value of my local storage goes to:

```js
{
    description: "The code supplied is not valid",
    error: "invalid_grant"
}
```

How can I keep my data in my LocalStorage ? 
Thanks !

Comment: There's a lot of info missing here. What is in localStorage after you refresh? Where does this error message come from? You should not be storing authentication tokens in localStorage either way

Comment: It's `Access_token` in your example, but `access_token` in the "output". _"...the local storage goes to..."_ - "local storage" goes nowhere. The error is clearly not from any `localStorage` operation hence where's the actual script that throws the error?

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited my post, Access_token is in key and access_token is in value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
localStorage.setItem('Access_token', token);
```

will reset the data each time you refresh the page.

You can first check if token is present before setting or re-setting it,

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('Access_token')){
    localStorage.setItem('Access_token', JSON.stringify(token));
}
```